# Книги и ресурсы по анализу кода

Tags: книги, code-analyst, linter, static-analysis

Меня интересует статический и динамический анализ кода для популярных языков (c++, python, java, c# и др.). Я бы хотел поисследовать его вглубь. Посоветуйте мне какие-нибудь книги или научные статьи на эту тему.

Comment: переведите ваш вопрос на русский, и добавьте информацию которая будет описывать определенную проблему

Comment: У нас такого эталонного ответа ещё нет, предлагаю попробовать собрать.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже сказал [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) такого вопроса здесь нет, и поэтому я начну сбор информации, а остальные дополнять кто чем считает нужным, поэтому ниже привожу то что я смог накопать :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Статический анализ кода:**

Для начала в Википедии есть [такая](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) интересная статья-список. В ней описываются инструменты для статического анализа кода. Есть инструменты как мультиязычные, так и заточенные под определенный язык. Так же есть такой инструмент как [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk4KT6rqG6QIVCaaaCh2_uwKoEAAYASAAEgJbmPD_BwE), его можно скачать и использовать для анализа своего кода. [Вот](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/61622133/StaticCodeAnalysisList) и [вот](https://www.viva64.com/en/t/0074/) два списка с ресурсами статического анализа.

**Динамический анализ кода:**

Для динамического анализа кода есть на той же Википедии есть [статья](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis) описывающая разные инструменты, техники и способы. [Сайт](https://owasp.org/www-community/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools) на котором приводится список с разными инструментами, как опенсорсными так и коммерческими.

**Полезные статьи и ссылки:**

1. Интересная [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/461173/?mobile=no) на Хабре.
2. Если интересует C# и .NET, то, конечно же, стоит смотреть в сторону Roslyn. Это позволяет легко писать анализаторы кода. Правда *что* именно анализировать - это нужно придумать самому.

   Читать можно любые книги по Розлину и официальную документацию. В частности:
   [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).
   Есть такая книга: Source Code Analytics With Roslyn and JavaScript Data Visualization. Сам пока не читал, но судя по содержанию - оно.

**Буду рад если присоединитесь и сделаете вклад в формирование данного ответа :)**

*P.S. Это мой первый общий вопрос, поэтому формат подачи информации может быть неверным. Заранее прошу прощения и если что-то изложено не так как нужно, то вы знаете что делать :)*

Comment: О, единорожки от PVS :) Только мне показалось, автор как раз спрашивает не инструменты, а как раз то, про что ты написал "надо придумывать самому".

Comment: @Qwertiy я ищу хорошие статьи, книги, материалы не только по тому "что нужно искать" (я сам использую с++, и некоторый опыт анализа синтаксических деревьев, кодовых путей, возможные проблемы с памятью привился сам по себе =) ). Скорее хотелось бы поисследовать существующие работы по этой теме, посмотреть как их можно интегрировать в повседневний процесс разработки без ущерба производительности разработчика... из того что я нашёл: 1) https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/3198e114c4b70702b27e6d88de2c92734c9ac4c0.pdf 2) https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5929241

Comment: Возможно получится дать математическое описание ограничений, которые пока преодолеть не получится. Вообщем, ищу всё "глубокое по этой теме" =)